# Problems with original Jquery script, it won't start!

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm suck a noob when it comes to java/jquery, I don't even know the basics. So please have understanding.

I've fetched this script from the jQuery website, but it won't start for me :/

What am I doing wrong?

The whole script is found on http://jsfiddle.net/xZUue/

Thank you for your help!

Comment: u have put jquery file but have you put the js file which scrolls images????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the miniscroller function on your div, like so:

```
$(function() {
  $("#scroller").miniscroller();
});
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/qJkdy/

Comment: Oh thanks man :)

Is there any way I can make this scroll vertically with 5 images at a time?

Comment: No problem. You will need to consult the documentation for 'miniscroller'. Do you have a link for the documentation?

Comment: http://romanovian.com/blog/2011/04/13/jquery-miniscroller/ - this is the documentation. It says that I only have to change from 'horizontal' to 'vertical' but this doesn't work for me. Damn I wish I understood java better..

Comment: When it's in "horizontal" mode it keeps scrolling the images, but when I change it to vertical it goes empty before restarting. Why is this?

Comment: Hey bro, I added some css to make the vertical version work, I also had to change the height of the scroller div to 200px. http://jsfiddle.net/qJkdy/2/

Comment: @FutureKode Thanks man! I'm trying to customize it to work on my site. The thing is that I'm putting it into a frame which is w:300 and h:500, and it's supposed to scroll company logos. I'd like this scroll to show about 4-5 images at a time and never become empty. For instance, let's say I divide these images into 2 groups, then I want the 2nd group to load when the first one is about to move. When the 2nd one is about to move, I want to reload the first one. Would this be possible? It seems pretty difficult..

Comment: According to the documentation you can specify the number of images to scroll at a time with 'itemsInGroup'. If you set that to 5 and have 10 images in your scroller each 100px tall then that would equal 2 groups of 5 images being scrolled.. did u try that?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is loaded and so is the plugin, but your not making any use of it!

**Do:**

> ```
> $('#scroller').miniscroller();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Check out..Its working...u were missing

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#scroller").miniscroller();
    });
</script>
```

updated link:  http://jsfiddle.net/xZUue/5/

Comment: How is your answer different from the two answers posted 10mins before yours?

Comment: @FutureKode: This page was jst open and i was implementing it over the url which he posted...and jst came and post answer...at that time it didnt show me any answer as i didnt refresh my page...anythning else?????